# method not spawning sprite properly

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody, skaction

Right now I have five bricks at the top of the screen all on the same y position and equally spaced apart. I would like to have five more breaks spawn outside of the top of the scene and slide down every 5 seconds. While the new bricks are sliding down I want the previous bricks to slide down to make room for the new. I want this sequence to continue on forever. I would like the new bricks to pick up the same properties of the old ones , such as when a ball hits them the react.

With the code I put in to accomplish this, I get a single brick spawning and then sliding down. Also the new brick does not act the same way as the old, it does not act like its a part of the physics world. How do I get 5 bricks spawning then sliding down and applying the same properties as the other bricks.

This code is the code I added to spawn more bricks:

```
-(void) spawnMoreBricks:(CGSize)size {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        SKSpriteNode *brick = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"brick"];
        //resize bricks
        brick.size = CGSizeMake(60, 30);
        //position it
        brick.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height);

        SKAction *wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:5];
        SKAction *spawn = [SKAction runBlock:^{[self addChild: brick];
            SKAction *move = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-80 duration:3];
            [brick runAction: move];
        }];

        SKAction *spawnSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[wait, spawn]];
        SKAction *repeatSequence = [SKAction repeatActionForever:spawnSequence];

        [self runAction:repeatSequence];
    }
}
```

This code adds the bricks into the scene right when it initializes, they react to the ball colliding with them and everything:

```
- (void) addBricks:(CGSize)size {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        //create brick sprite from image
        SKSpriteNode *brick = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"brick"];
        //resize bricks
        brick.size = CGSizeMake(60, 30);
        //psoition bricks
        int xPos = size.width/5 * (i+.5);
        int yPos = size.height - 25;
        brick.position = CGPointMake(xPos, yPos);
        brick.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:brick.frame.size];
        brick.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        brick.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = brickCategory;

        //add bricks to scene
        [self addChild:brick];
    }
}
```

Comment: By the looks of your first bit of code, when you set the new bricks x position, they are all on top of eachother at the top of the screen, which might explain why you only see one new brick? Also you don't apply the same physicsbody properties to the new bricks like you did to the originals.

Comment: Please use the { } icon to add code, not the code snippet button (it is only for JS/HTML/CSS)

Comment: I would suspect this code `runBlock:^{[self addChild: brick];` given `brick` is reassigned.